# Xcode 6.3 - You already have a current iOS Development certificate or a pending certificate request

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning

Xcode as of 6.3 is no longer allowing me to automatically perform device provisioning for a client.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?  I found no results when searching for this on Google...

This client has their own bundle ID and it's possible they also have their own provisioning profile for this device.  So maybe Apple is matching up the bundle ID irrespective of the developer account being used for provisioning.

I was able to address the issue by modifying the app's bundle ID and manually going through the provisioning process, but I'm guessing this issue is extremely rare, so I'm not sure if this post will be of use to anyone.

Comment: I just received this as well, I'm definitely in the same boat. I'm loathed to start down a path of just deleting access and keys hoping it will reset given I'm fairly new to Xcode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just found that if I remove my account from Xcode, and then sign in again, it solved the issue. I did revoke my existing certificates and request new ones though as part of that process. I didn't import an existing profile.

Comment: I try with your steps but my problem was not fix, Please check how can I resolved this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701062/xcode-6-3-you-already-have-a-current-ios-development-certificate-or-a-pending/49979593#49979593.

Answer (score 26):

When I am create new certificate from my Xcode 9.2 the error was appear
`"You already have a current iOS Distribution certificate or a pending certificate request"`.

Just 2 step for fix this error.

1. Remove old certificate from developer.apple.com
2. Create new certificate from Xcode or developer.apple.com

My problem has been solved **(I am using Xcode 9.2).**

Comment: How do I remove the certificate from the site?

Comment: You can hire me for this task :), Joke a part, just search on google.

Comment: I am using free provisioning, I don't have a certificate.

Comment: Try to change bund id and run project again.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712697

Answer (score 17):

My team has maxed out on release certificates, because apparently there is a quota.
We had to delete one of the existing release certificates.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This issue is actually more common than you think.

**Some Solutions:**

I usually find that opening Xcode's settings and signing out of my account and the signing in again resolves most of those issues.

You may have an older mac that already used up that one allotted development certificate. In that case you'll want to export the developer profile from that machine. If you no longer have access to that machine, it may be time to invalidate that certificate and simply request a new one.

Another option may be to double check your build settings in your project and ensure that it's looking for the right certificate. It's fairly common in my experience for these settings to make decisions on their own, and confirming that they're what you expect may help.

**Background:**

When dealing with provisioning, it's really easy to get caught up with the frustration of all of the steps you need to go through. The first thing to note is if the error you see is talking about a "Certificate" or a "Profile." In your case, it's a certificate. Good.

Certificates differ from provisioning profiles in a few ways. Certificates are usually only generated twice: once for development, and once for distribution. (Exceptions to this rule are if you decide to add support for some of the special features like push notification or for generating passbook passes on a server.)

The process for generating certificates is also a little more bureaucratic than profiles. You *request* a certificate from Apple's Member Center. You *generate* a provisioning profile.

The reason for the word *request* vs *generate* is because both Apple and your iOS team's admin need to approve certificate requests. This is because certificates identify you as part of your iOS developer team, and offer all the powers associated with that.

For the sake of completeness, I'll add that provisioning profiles are generated based on that certificate, and really only tell iOS what environment your app is meant to run in. (On any device via the store, specific devices, etc.)

Now, the important part for you is the request business. Most people don't pay much attention to this terminology, since indie developers and small teams (where the developers are admins) don't require developers to ask for permission.

Your error is talking about a previously generated certificate or request. You can only have one development certificate per developer. You either have one, or you've requested one and someone has to approve.

That's what's happening here.

Answer (score 4):

This process is made simple with Xcode 8.3 and 9. Just delete one of your old certifcates in the "validate" interface and click the plus button to request new one, Xcode will request for you and add it in keychain. in my case, maximum number was reached, so I deleted one which was lost in a old Mac  and created new one.

Comment: ty for this hint! where is the 'validate interface'? I do not see it.

Comment: Xcode should prompt you with the validate interface when there is a certificate issue.

Comment: XCode does not prompt with any "validate interface" and typing that in help does not lead to anything...

Comment: we had 3 distribution profiles. for me it work to delete on and create a new distribution file

Answer (score 4):

This error may also be occur if you reach your distribution certificate limit. After creating 3 iOS Distribution Certificates in an account, the following error message will be displayed when you try to create 4th one: "You already have a current Distribution certificate or a pending certificate request."

Open this link
https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/add

Press + icon in front of Certificate

[image: Press + icon in front of Certificate Label]

Check **Apple Distribution** section if its show the red text as shown in image then you should revoke you existing certificates to generate new one because you have reached you limit.

[image]

Just 2 step for fix this error.

1. Remove old certificate from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/add)
2. Create new certificate from Xcode or developer.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

Delete old developer certificate from https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/ and try to create developer certificate from xcode

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove old certificate from apple developer account.
2) Go to the 'Xcode' 3) Select 'Preferences' option and then Select the 'Account' Tab 
3) Select apple id from left side and click on 'Manage Certificate'.
4) Click on '+' (add certificate) button.
5) Add 'Apple Distribution' Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, only a macbook *restart* resolved this for me.

Creating another Distribution certificate was not an option, because it had already reached the max. number of certificates.

I manually added an existing one (incl. its private key) to the Keychain …and still Xcode said "Not in Keychain". I then tried to trigger a refresh of the Xcode listing by removing & adding my developer account to Xcode, but that didn't work — neither did restarting Xcode.
So, when all else fails, you try to reboot your system.

Answer (score 0):

When you have three active distribution certificates that were created on distinct machines, you'll see this issue. You can either ask for the private key of a previously made one or simply revoke any of them and make your own.

Comment: How?  How do you do that?